# Is ReactorDebugAgent suitable for production?

Tags: java, project-reactor, javaagents

I read how to enable `ReactorDebugAgent` here:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor-tools-debug

But I don't know if it's feasible to have such debug agent enabled by default 
on the production environment or only when something unusual happens?

Comment: Seems it's okay to use in prod, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rnMIueRKNU&feature=youtu.be&t=3316

Comment: @123 I cannot accept comments ;) If you want you can convert your comment to fully qualified answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [section](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor-tools-debug) name, [as of 18th Feb 2022](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/6de1cd7562289aa5d412d3b372f869ba63d184c5/docs/asciidoc/debugging.adoc#production-ready-global-debugging), is:

> 7.4. Production-ready Global Debugging

which seems to suggest that it is indeed suitable to be used in production. To add further context, the agent:

> instruments your code and adds debugging info without paying the cost of capturing the stacktrace on every operator call. The behaviour is very similar to Activating Debug Mode - aka tracebacks, but without the runtime performance overhead.

To add some more context, we have been using this agent in a service with ~500 rps and ~5ms response time, and have not faced any issue, and have benefited from the traceback with assembly information

Answer (score -1):

add     `ReactorDebugAgent.init();` in your spring main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReactorDebugAgent.init();
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-tools</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/28/reactor-debugging-experience

Comment: in my question I wondered if this is suitable for production. I know how to setup it ;)

Comment: OK, got you. let's keep it as a reference then.